# Texstudio script for deleting $ $

Tags: texstudio, javascript

I was wondering how can create a texstudio script for removing the $ $ notation. what is the problem of following code.

```
%SCRIPT
txt = cursor.selectedText()
txt.replace("$","")
editor.write(txt)
cursor.clearSelection()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Charles Stewart I finnaly got the answer

```
%SCRIPT
var txt = cursor.selectedText()
var str = txt.replace(/[$]/g,"")
editor.replaceSelectedText(str)
cursor.clearSelection()
```

Answer (score 3):

Fixed attempt:

```
%SCRIPT
var txt = cursor.selectedText()
editor.replaceSelectedText( txt.replace(/[$]/g,"") )
cursor.clearSelection()
```

The syntax of regular expressions and the replace method are documented on the MDN at their [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions) and [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) pages.

Comment: Thank you, but no that doesn't work. The problem seems to be in the replace function from string.

Comment: @Hamid I've updated my answer: the replace method only replaces once when invoked with a string as first argument.  Hopefully this now works.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
Sorry, No. Where can some one find the documentation for replace method?

Comment: @Hamid I see you have figured things out.  For the sake of other readers I have fixed my answer and provided links to documentation.